# Using attenuators to damp reflections on transmission line?

Tags: power, rf, transmission-line

I have a 3m long transmission line that transmits a 100ns bipolar square pulse every 200us. At the beginning of the coax cable is a pulsing circuit board, that generates the waveform, then it sends the pulse through a 50 ohm 3 m long coax line and at the other end of the coax line is connected to a load of 20 ohm.

I have noticed that by placing 6dB attenuators near at the output of the pulsing board then attaching the coax lines in series results in a greater power output from the load.

Is this due to the damping of reflections?

In addition would placing the attenuation close to the load result in a greater power transfer since the reflections are attenuated before travelling back a good portion of the cable?
I can not try this scenario yet as I do not have the correct connectors to attempt this.

Comment: What is the load? How do you measure its power output? How many 6-dB attenuators did you put between the source board and the cable?

Comment: Also, what are the rise and fall times of your pulse?

Comment: @ThePhoton the load is a piezoelectric transducer I am measuring the strength of the pressure wave. The rise and fall times are roughly 2 - 4ns.

Comment: Adding a 6-dB attenuator should reduce the delivered power by about 4x. Even if there is a benefit from reducing reflections, I wouldn't expect a net increase in output power due to these effects. More likely there is something going on with a nonlinearity in the piezo device or related to the fact the piezo is not a resistive load. Piezo's aren't my area, but I'd guess that more details about the device could help someone give you a good answer.

Comment: What is the bandwidth of your pressure-measurement instrument? If it isn't on the order of 10 MHz or more, the apparent increase in power could be nothing more than a shift of energy from frequencies outside its bandwith to those inside the bandwidth. This could occur even if the total power delivered to the transducer is less.

Comment: @DaveTweed The measuring instrument can measure up to 50Mhz. However, just to clarify, are you suggesting that the attenuators are causing some frequencies to be amplified while others attenuated or are you suggesting that the attenuator is creating frequencies that did not exist in the signal before? The attenuators I am using are 6 db from 0 - 3Ghz.

Comment: No, the attenuators are quite linear and are not creating new frequencies. But your pulse waveform is quite rich in harmonics, and the attenuator interacting with either the driver or the cable could be drastically modifying the system frequency response.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of attenuation, consider matching the load to the transmission line with a transformer.

Z1 = (turns ratio)^2 * Z2

Try a turns ratio of 11/7

Answer (score 1):

You can use a transformer as john suggested, if you can find or make one, or you can use a 30 ohm resistor in series with your load:

20 + 30 = 50, which matches the cable.

You might not be able to get exactly 30 ohms in one package, so you may have to use 27 or 33 or a series/parallel combination of other values to get closer to 30.  But even 27 or 33 will be a lot better than what you have now.